# Slow UITabBar item loading

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

There is the problem in my project, this problem can bring lots of unpleasant feelings for customer.
So app is basically ground on `UITabBarController` and when I want to load one of `UIViewController` it loads too long (~ 1.5s in first launch and after switching there is seeing pause) - its very bad for user experience, as you know.
So I want to know some way to preload this section before user want to enter there (section doesn't loads first). There are few questions which can be the same with first glance but I don't want to have a solution like "spinner while loading".
If anybody knows elegant solution I'll very thankful.

Alexey

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like you do lot of work in either your init method, the `viewDidLoad` or the `viewWillAppear` method of your `UIViewController`. 
On the first load I don't know an answer, but you could load the other view controllers in the `UITabBarController` in a background thread so they are loaded when you tap them.

**EDIT:**
On first load you could use a very simple start screen and load the first screen also on the background thread. But then you would have to add a new view.